Query string causing angular application break
I have an angular website is is already live and working fine. There are some google keyword query string which is attached to our url for tracking. When the url is loaded with query string such as below, whole website is crashed. If I make any minor change in the below url it again worked fine. For eg
htttps://ourwebsite.com/contractor-onboarding-and-enablement?campaign=world%20New%20Pages&adgroup=Sales%20Coaching&keyword=top-rated%20sales%20enablement%20platforms


Now again same url with below query works fine.
?campaign=newwebsite%20New%20Pages&adgroup=Sales%20Coaching&keyword=top-rated%20sales%20enablement%20platforms

There is hardly any deference between these two keywords. I could not add any fixes because the script dont even load. These scripts which shows Failed to load module script but when open same script in new window with hard refresh works fine. I could see the script inside it.
My question is how a query string is causing script to not load ?

its webserver issue, kindly configure your webserver to serve angular single page applications

As said my application working completly fine with or without query string. Its just some specific query string causing issue.
